# Motion Detector Time Adjustment

Tags: motion, detector

What it means when adjustment area is: 10±5 s-10min? I cannot find a solution from Google.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. It means the minimum time is 10±5  seconds, and the maximum time is 10 minutes. Also, this doesn't seem to be an electronics design, but an electronics usage question.

Comment: There's switch what you can adjust in degrees. The instruction book shows that "Adjustment area/range is: 10±5 s-10min". I don't really get it why it's 10±5 and not in example 5s-10min. I don't really get that ± sign meaning and s-10min. So if I set switch on maximum it should be turned on the next 10 minutes? How do I interpret the adjustment range "10±5 s-10min"

Comment: The +/- sign means they can only guarantee that on the lowest setting it will be somewhere between 5 and 15 seconds.

Comment: Wow. That was quite simple. I were thinking too complicated. Thanks a lot for making me feel so damn stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I don't really get it why it's 10±5 and not in example 5s-10min."

Because they they are telling you that the minimum could be anywhere between 5 s and 15 s. They can't guarantee that you can get down to 5 s so they wouldn't specify it like that. 
They designer probably aimed for 10 s and guarantee that it will be 10 ± 5 s.

---

Note that there should be a space between the digits and units as per SI standard. We don't write "53bananas" but rather "53 bananas". It's the same with volts, amps, seconds, etc.